# VBA Copying Multiple sheets selected Data ranges to a workbook by creating a new workbook automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook of 80 worksheets,and I want to select only 4 worksheets with selected range. I want to copy this range a new workbook automatically. I have run a macro and this code below.

```
Sub TestTest()
'
 ' TestTest Macro
 '

 '
  Sheets("Summary").Select
  Range("A1:O54").Select
  Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Newworkbook.xlsx", 
 FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Windows("").Activate
Sheets("").Select
Range("").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Newworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("").Activate
Sheets("").Select
Range("").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Newworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("").Activate
Sheets("").Select
Range("").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Newworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("").Activate
Sheets("").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
Range("").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Newworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("").Activate
Range("N29").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first selected range goes from B1 to Column O, but the others go from B1 to Column Q, are these ranges that you want to copy always different? I understand that the number of rows may vary, but so do the columns?

Comment: Hi Xabier, Yes these are the fixed ranges i want to copy for this worksheet. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work as you expect it to, it will copy all five ranges and paste them into a new workbook, renaming each of the sheets appropriately and then save the newly created workbook to your desired location, you might want to add something to the name of the new workbook you are creating, such as a date, so as to not give you any issues the next time you run the code, alternatively you could delete the previous report and overwrite it:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet: Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
Dim wsMeasured As Worksheet: Set wsMeasured = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1. Measured Work")
Dim wsPreliminaries As Worksheet: Set wsPreliminaries = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2. Preliminaries")
Dim wsFees As Worksheet: Set wsFees = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3. Fees")
Dim wsContingency As Worksheet: Set wsContingency = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4. Contingency")
Dim NewWorkBook As Workbook
'above declare and set the worksheets and workbook you are working with
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set NewWorkBook = Workbooks.Add
    'add a new workbook

    wsSummary.Range("A1:O54").Copy 'copy first range
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    'paste into first sheet in new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Name = "Summary" 'rename the sheet in the new workbook

    wsMeasured.Range("B1:Q76").Copy 'copy second range
    NewWorkBook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'add a new sheet to the new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    'paste into second sheet in new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(2).Name = "1. Measured Work" 'rename the sheet in the new workbook

    wsPreliminaries.Range("B1:Q48").Copy 'copy third range
    NewWorkBook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'add a new sheet to the new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    'paste into third sheet in new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(3).Name = "2. Preliminaries" 'rename the sheet in the new workbook

    wsFees.Range("B1:Q47").Copy 'copy fourth range
    NewWorkBook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'add a new sheet to the new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(4).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(4).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    'paste into fourth sheet in new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(4).Name = "3. Fees" 'rename the sheet in the new workbook

    wsContingency.Range("B1:Q46").Copy 'copy fifth range
    NewWorkBook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'add a new sheet to the new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(5).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(5).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    'paste into fifth sheet in new workbook
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(5).Name = "4. Contingency" 'rename the sheet in the new workbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'deselect copied range

    NewWorkBook.SaveAs Filename:="NewWorkBook.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    'save the newly created workbook
    NewWorkBook.Close
    'close the newly created workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier,thanks again the problem i am having now is i want to save the file on different user's system, where i want the system to not set a pre-defined path.

Comment: say for example we have different users that have access to the document, so if i have my path saved they wont be able to run Macro.....

Comment: @sathiyasat do your other users share a mapped drive? I don't know where you would like to save the file to for another user to have access to it unless you share a common drive. Please could you mark my response as an answer as it did what you expected in your original question? Thanks.

Comment: i want the new file  to save the file on their desktop.

Comment: @sathiyasat do you have access to their desktop in Windows Explorer? I doubt you do have access, and as such it isn't possible to save it to a path which you don't have access to, but if you somehow do have access to that path, then you can amend the path in the code to that one and that should do it.

Comment: thanks very much, what if i just want the file to open once it is copied? i would just let the users choose to save.

Comment: @sathiyasat you would just have to remove or comment out the penultimate two lines `NewWorkBook.SaveAs ...` and `NewWorkBook.Close`, this will leave the newly created workbook open to let the user do whatever they want with it.

Comment: how can i copy formatting from current range to new sheet?

Comment: @sathiyasat I've updated the code to `xlPasteAll` this should paste formats as well as values. Hope it helps. Also when you said that you want to save the New workbook to another user's desktop, did you mean that they will be running the code and therefore their desktop will be within their local pc? If so, then the code can be amended to save directly to the user's desktop.

Comment: I have made above changes works like a miracle, you are the best.

Comment: the code also copies formulas, but i would like to know if there is a way to copy formatting but not Formulas.Regards

Comment: @sathiyasat amended the code to copy values and formats only. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: i have used the following to adjust the width and height of the columns and rows but row height doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").EntireRow.AutoFit
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Comment: Try: `NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit` & `NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit`

Comment: i have a quick question about how to change SharePoint HillBilly Tabs. I want to change the width of them. we are  using JQuery, Can you Help?